# On the definition of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

I have a question regarding the definition of integral for functions that are continuous in an open interval $(a, b)$ but are not necessarily defined or continuous at the endpoints $a, b$.

Courant and John, in the book "*Introduction to Calculus and Analysis*", define it in the following way:

> If the limit $$F = \lim_\limits{\epsilon \to 0}
> \int_{\alpha_\epsilon}^{\beta_\epsilon} f(x) \ dx$$ exists when $\
> a < \alpha_\epsilon < \beta_\epsilon < b \ $ and $ \  
> \lim_\limits{\epsilon \to 0} \ \alpha_\epsilon = a, \  $ $
> \lim_\limits{\epsilon \to 0} \ \beta_\epsilon = b,\ $ and if  $F$ is
> independent of the particular choice of $\alpha_\epsilon$ and
> $\beta_\epsilon$ we say that the improper integral $\int_a^b f(x) \
> dx$ converges and has value $F$.

The way I interpret this definition is:

- Let $(\alpha_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(\beta_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be two arbitrary real sequences converging to $a$ and $b$, respectively, such that $$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}): \ a < \alpha_n < \beta_n < b. \ $$ If for each $n \in \mathbb{N},$ the definite integral $\int_{\alpha_n}^{\beta_n} f(x) \ dx $ has the same value $F$, we say that the improper integral $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx$ converges and has value $F$.

I feel they could have also wrote something like this:

- If the limit $$F = \lim_\limits{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\alpha + \epsilon}^{\beta - \epsilon} f(x) \ dx$$ (where the points $\ \alpha + \epsilon\ $ and $ \ \beta - \epsilon \ $ approach the endpoints $a$ and $b$, respectively, from the interior of the interval) exists, then we say that the improper integral $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx$ converges and has value $F$.

Are these rewordings of the definition correct? I'm just not quite sure what they mean by "*if $F$ is independent of the particular choice of $\alpha_\epsilon$ and $\beta_\epsilon$*".

Comment: These are subtly different. The first has two separate limits; yours takes both at the same time.

Comment: It is important that the two limits can be taken at unrelated rates and yield the same result, otherwise you may have "catastrophic cancellation" yielding something akin to the Cauchy principal value.

Comment: @FlipTack Thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate on that? I'm not sure I understand the subtlety.

Comment: @Blackmetalboy Sure, let me write everything up in an answer.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand what you mean by "catastrophic cancellation" and "Cauchy principal value". However from your comment and FlipTack's one, I see that I'm somehow taking both limits at the same time, which may lead into trouble.

Comment: As for "if F is independent of the particular choice..." that's just saying it holds for any arbitrary sequences you choose, which is the definition of a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to mention here.

1. The first definition says $\lim_{t \to 0} \alpha_\epsilon =  \lim _{t \to 0} \beta_\epsilon= 0$. Surely you want these to converge to the endpoints $\alpha,\beta$? Not sure if this is a typo on your behalf or their behalf.
2. In your interpretation of the first definition, you talk about the definite integral having the "same value F" along these sequences - this is not the case. The value of the integral may change, we're just looking for what it converges to. (The idea is that we take ANY pair of sequences and look at what the integral tends to. If it's the same value in every case, the improper integral is said to converge to that value. If even one choice of sequences yields a different value, the improper integral doesn't converge.)
3. Your second definition is not the same - the first allows the limit to be taken at separate rates, which is important.

To elaborate on that last point, consider evaluating

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \tan x \, \text{d} x$$

which does not converge by the first definition, but does by the second.

**Why?** We have $\int_{\alpha_n}^{\beta_n} \tan x \, \text{d}x = \ln \frac{\cos \alpha_n}{\cos \beta_n}$. If we use the second definition, then we always have $\alpha_n = -\beta_n$ and so the integral is $0$ for every $n$, hence $0$ in the limit. However if $\beta_n$ and $\alpha_n$ are independent, we can let $\beta_n \to \pi / 2$ at a much faster rate than $\alpha_n \to -\pi/2$, so asymptotically $\ln \frac{\cos \alpha_n}{\cos \beta_n} \sim +\infty$. Similarly, if $\alpha_n$ converges faster, then $\ln \frac{\cos \alpha_n}{\cos \beta_n} \sim -\infty$.

Your proposed definition is in fact related to the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), which you may be interested in looking at.

Comment: +1 especially for point 3 and its example

Comment: Thank you for adding the details.
1) I've checked and what I wrote is the definition they have wrote in the book. I want both $\alpha_\epsilon$ and $\beta_\epsilon$ to converge to the endpoints $a$ and $b$ respectively (I think you mistakenly typed $\alpha$ and $\beta$)

2) Oh, of course. I see what you mean. Would it be correct to say that at some point, the value of the integral along these sequences has to be the same?

3) I see. Could you please give an example of what would happen if I were to not allow the limit to be taken at separate rates?

Comment: @FlipTack Oops, i'm sorry. You are correct, I had a typo in point 1). The values of the limits must be $a$ and $b$, respectively, and not 0, of course. I corrected it now.

Comment: @Blackmetalboy The idea is that we take ANY pair of sequences and look at what the integral converges to. If it's the same value in every case, the integral is said to converge to that value. If even one choice of sequences yields a different value, the integral doesn't converge.

Comment: @Blackmetalboy I've added an example of an integral where this distinction matters. Let me know if it requires more elaboration!

Comment: @FlipTack Ah! I see! You cleared all my doubts and addressed all of my points. The example, its explanation and this last comment were enlightening. If you were to put this last comment also in your answer, I think it would be nice. It may be helpful if someone else has the same question and for some reason does not read the comments. Thank you so much! I'm not sure how the policy for accepting answers works. I'm inclined to accept your answer right now, but perhaps I should wait a bit longer in case someone is also writing something relevant to add up to your points.

Comment: @FlipTack I've accepted your answer. Thank you!